# Debian 9 (Stretch): How to create SFTP file exchange between various machines?

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd, sftp, shared-folders

**Imagine the following setup:**

- Two laptops: Let's call them [*laptop A*] and [*laptop B*].
- Each laptop has the same operating system installed (Debian 9 Stretch)
- Each laptop has `openssh-server` installed
- Each laptop has `firewalld` and `firewall-config` installed
- Each laptop has `qemu-kvm` installed
- Each laptop is running a VM via `qemu-kvm`
- The file exchange between VM and its host (= laptop host system) is provided by SFTP-exchange

Saying this, the file exchange between VMs and their belonging hosts is working completely fine by accessing hosts `/home`-directory via `sftp://user@192.168.122.1` from the guest.

**Example:** It is possible to share files between [*laptop A*] and [*virtual machine A*] or between [*laptop B*] and [*virtual machine B*] using SFTP-exchange via command above.

**But - the more interesting question now is:**

How can I share files between...

1. [*laptop A*] and [*laptop B*]?
2. [*laptop A*] and [*virtual machine B*]?
3. [*laptop B*] and [*virtual machine A*]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not really SSH-related. In order to do this the VMs must be able to reach the network outside the laptops (i.e. their interface has to be bridged or their traffic has to be routed / NATed) and their must be reachable from there is the connection shall be initiated from the laptop.

If you bridge the interface or route the traffic and give the VM a visible IP address then you must allow forwarding the traffic in the laptop firewall. In case of NAT you have to define a port and create a DNAT rule in nat/PREROUTING for it. But I am not sure if this is possible at all because I do not use this configuration.